# how to save dates into database using django?

Tags: django, date, format

this is my code

views.py

```
def guardar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        idpersona = int(request.POST.get('id'))
        persona = personal.objects.get(id=idpersona)
        idep = int(request.POST.get('dependencia'))
        dep = dependencia.objects.get(id=idep)
        idcon = int(request.POST.get('concepto'))
        con = concepto.objects.get(id=idcon)
        fecha = request.POST.get('fecha')
        print(fecha)
        db_registro = lista_registro(
            personal_id=persona,
            fecha_registro=fecha,
            dependencia_id=dep,
            concepto_id=con,
            descripcion=request.POST.get('descripcion'),
            monto=request.POST.get('monto'),
        )
        db_registro.save()

    return render(request, 'registro/exito.html')
```

Models.py

```
class lista_registro(models.Model):
    personal_id = models.ForeignKey(personal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dependencia_id = models.ForeignKey(dependencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    concepto_id = models.ForeignKey(concepto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_realizado = models.DateField()
    fecha_registro = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pago_id = models.ForeignKey(pago, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=2)
    monto = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
           return "===> " + self.descripcion + " <==="
```

well my problem is that I get a NOT NULL constraint error. I get that this is a date error but I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show the full traceback and error message when you ask questions - it will show exactly where the error is occuring. It looks like it is the `fecha_realizado` field that is causing the problem. You can avoid the error by either setting `null=True` on the field, or by setting a value before you save it (e.g. `fecha_realizado=fecha`).

Comment: Note that it's not a good idea to fetch data from `request.POST` like this. Django forms are very helpful for tasks like this, in particular [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: Instead of operating directly on the request parameters you should be cleaning and validating your data with a Django Form.

Comment: I know it is not safe to fetch data from request.POST but in the django forms the default widget for a foreign key field is a select input and I have to handle like 300 data. I did not found other way. (English it is not my natural language so sorry if I can't explain myself well)

Answer (score 0):

when you define a field that will not be required just set null=True, blank=True on your models file

```
fecha_realizado = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```